# Install OsClass On ubuntu

Tags: apache2, lamp

I'm trying to build a website using OsClass, I was working under windows + easyphp to do so. Last week I moved to ubuntu, I followed this guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Joomla to setup my Osclass site project (I created an "osclass" folder in "www" changed all permissions...), but when I type in my browser "localhost/osclass I just get this error:
Not Found
The requested URL /osclass was not found on this server.
Can someone please tell me what's wrong?
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Do you know if the services you installed are running, apache and MySQL need to be running for this to work. open a terminal and type:

```
sudo service apache2 status
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql status
```

Comment: Yes, all services are running:
 * apache2 is running
*Server version  5.5.43-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
Protocol version 10
Connection  Localhost via UNIX socket
UNIX socket  /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Uptime:   4 hours 6 min 3 sec
Threads: 1  Questions: 148  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 60  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 53  Queries per second avg: 0.010

Comment: ok next, have you checked the apache config file to verify it's root path?

Comment: do you mean this line: #ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"?

Comment: have a look at /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

Comment: this one apache2.conf

Comment: DocumentRoot /var/www/html       DocumentRoot /var/www/osclass

Comment: ok, so check to see if your installation created an html folder and if so move OSClass to /var/www/html/osclass

Comment: but I can't yet access the osclass installer, there is only the decompressed files from osclass zip file...

Comment: right, but if you have moved the unzipped files to /var/www/html/osclass/unzipped_docs/ then 'chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/osclass/'     open a browser and goto http://localhost/osclass. cross fingers should be working

Comment: Sorry it's not working!

Comment: ok I don't mind a challenge, so I am installing it on my laptop now will post results in 5 minutes or less - using Ubuntu 14.04.2

Comment: ok mine is running, are you ok with a team-viewer session?

Comment: otherwise we could start from the top - and reinstall, this is what I did: opened terminal: sudo apt-get install tasksel  - installed lamp - then - sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin - then started services - moved osclass to /var/www/html/osclass.zip - then - unzip osclasss.zip - chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/ - then deleted index.html

Comment: Thank you very much A1 Computers for all your help, Your solution worked.
Regards

Comment: Please upvote so others see this is the solution that worked